# Is it legal to embed the fonts that come with Adobe Reader in a PDF and distribute that PDF?

Tags: fonts, pdf, legal

By downloading [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) I obtain these fonts:

- `Adobe Pi Std` (regular)
- `Courier Std` (regular, **bold**, *italic*, ***bold-italic***)
- `Minion Pro` (regular, **bold**, *italic*, ***bold-italic***)
- `Myriad Pro` (regular, **bold**, *italic*, ***bold-italic***)

Is it legal to embed these fonts in a PDF and distribute that PDF?

Comment: And the answer is yes according to that question.

Comment: @ardentsonata Please post your answer as "answer" :) , if you are sure, thank you.

Comment: Well, considering that it is also your question and you have already accepted that answer, I'm fairly certain it's a moot point for me to reiterate an answer you've accepted. :x OP can do so if they wish though.

Comment: But does that change the fact that you are not distributing the actual font file? Citing that answer: "You may also embed the font in the resultant PDF file or EPS file that you create for the logo for placement in other content. What you cannot do is give out the font file itself to others. By having the font embedded in the PDF or EPS".

Comment: Yes the answer is already in that question you mentioned, but that question was not focused specifically to Adobe Reader fonts, but this is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9515/discussion-between-ardentsonata-and-peter-sivak)

Comment: The generic answer is "check the license" the specific answer is "nearly all Adobe font licenses allow PDF embedding".

Comment: Peter, I understand where you're coming from, but the answer to the other question also fits perfectly for this question. Since that is the case, I agree this should be closed as a duplicate. Don't worry, people will still be able to search for this one and see that it is answered elsewhere!

Comment: Ok, no problem :)